# Pine Script Strategy Not Showing Short Position Closes; Only Closing Long Positions

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to get each trade to close two bars after being opened.  I'm using this to backtest some binary option strategies.  I can't figure out why the Long positions are working, but the Short positions are not showing any closes.

Also, I want "calc_on_every_tick" to be active, but when I add "and strategy.opentrades==0" to my buy and sell signal variables, to prevent multiple Longs and Shorts on the same candle, all Long and Short signals disappear from the chart.  My best guess is that this is happening because the Short positions are not being closed, but I'm not sure.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

```
barsTillClose = input.int(2, minval=1, title="Amount of Bars Till Close Position")

buy_signal = crossUp// and strategy.opentrades==0
sel_signal = crossDo// and strategy.opentrades==0
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, qty=1, when=buy_signal)
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, qty=1, when=sel_signal)

// Track the Entry Bar
entryTime = float(na)
timeClose = bool(na)
entryTime := timeClose[1] ? na : strategy.position_size[0] > strategy.position_size[1] ? bar_index : entryTime[1]

// See if we need to close
timeClose := bar_index >= entryTime+(barsTillClose-1)
strategy.close('Long', when=timeClose)
strategy.close('Short', when=timeClose)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index()` built-in to find the entry bar. There is one for time as well, among other useful values. 0 is the first open trade. I substituted some variables to make the script complete.

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

barsTillClose = input.int(2, minval=1, title="Amount of Bars Till Close Position")

sma1 = ta.sma(close, 21)
sma2 = ta.sma(close, 50)

crossUp = ta.crossover(sma1, sma2)
crossDo = ta.crossunder(sma1, sma2)

buy_signal = crossUp// and strategy.opentrades==0
sel_signal = crossDo// and strategy.opentrades==0
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, qty=1, when=buy_signal)
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, qty=1, when=sel_signal)

// Track the Entry Bar
entryTime = strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(0)

// See if we need to close
timeClose = bar_index >= entryTime+(barsTillClose-1)

strategy.close('Long', when=timeClose)
strategy.close('Short', when=timeClose)
```

Cheers and all the best

Comment: Thank you very much.  This fixed it.  Also, just a quick sidenote, your scripts on TradingView are fantastic.  Your Key Levels indicator has saved me many times.

Comment: Cheers my friend, glad it is working, and thank you for the kind words